# How to unlock locked doors in "Advanced Test Drive" quest?

Tags: starbound

In the Starbound quest [Advanced Test Drive](https://starbounder.org/Advanced_Test_Drive), there are some locked doors:

[image]

I want to loot whatever is behind them. How to get there?

Comment: There is a key in Starbound to show up lines between doors and their triggers. You may enable it and follow the line.

Comment: If you mean wire editor - that does not work in protected areas.